# Drupal app development

Tags: drupal

```
name = MagApp 1.0
description = Magapp module that enables MagApp powered publications.
core = 7.x
php = 5.1
package = MagApp
dependencies[] = references
dependencies[] = node_reference
dependencies[] = magapp_core_content_types
version = "7.x-2.0"
```

I have been created a module and the info file is written above is there any problem while changing the php version , Because i did it before months , so i have to update this module , Can i add dependencies directly without using modules .

Comment: There's a separate [Stack Exchange site for Drupal questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/). However, odds are this question has already been asked and answered - please search before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the source of /modules for admin/structure and check how they built that *_menu() hook.

If you have access to the server and it's running *NIX you could do:

```
grep -ri 'admin/structure' your_site_directory/modules/*
```

And then you can implement your own [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in your own module. Might also be possible in the Structure -> Menu system of the web UI. I don't recall.